# Каково назначение :: в именах внутри CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, cmakelists

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что в значит `::` в `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: обращение через `namespace`

Comment: немного контекста вопросу не помешало бы... скорей всего это просто часть имени импортированной цели без какого-то специального значения...

Comment: Я имею в виду `::`, которое ставится перед именем, но после псевдонима. `::` является частью имени или же это аналог раскрытия области видимости (как в `C++`)?